# How to retrieve properties from a List of Class in Dart?

Tags: list, class, dart, element, flutter

I created a custom Class with 4 elements here...

```
class Top {
  String videoId;
  int rank;
  String title;
  String imageString;

  Top({this.videoId, this.rank, this.title, this.imageString});
}
```

I'm retrieving some Firebase items to populate these elements..

```
var top = new Top(videoId: items['vidId'], rank: items['Value'],
title: items['vidTitle'], imageString: items['vidImage']);
```

Then I'm adding them to a List of Type "Top" in order to sort the Class values based on "rank"...

```
List<Top> videos = new List();
videos..sort((a, b) => a.rank.compareTo(b.rank));
videos.add(top);
```

But, printing `videos` logs this...

```
[Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top']
```

I'm not sure if its because its in a List.  How can I get usable "Top" property values from videos?  For instance when I query `top.rank` I get this...

```
[14, 12, 11, 10, 10, 6, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The properties of a list is obtained with `[]` operator passing the index of the element.

If you wanted retrive third `Top` in the list `videos` you can just access it like

```
videos[3]
```

If you wanted retrive a property `rank` of third `Top` in the list `videos` you can just access it like

```
videos[3].rank
```

If you want the print statement tho show items of list, then change your class to override `toString` method, like

```
class Top {
  String videoId;
  int rank;
  String title;
  String imageString;

 Top({this.videoId, this.rank, this.title, this.imageString});

 @override
 String toString(){
     return "{videoId: $videoId, rank: $rank, title: $title, imageString: $imageString}";
 }
}
```

Hope that helped!